# Ploting a black and white curve using pylab

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have drawn some colored ROC curves using pylab. For that purpose, I have put the following command in a for loop:

```
pl.plot(fprList [i], tprList[i],  color = colors[colorIndex],  label= str (fileNames [i].split('.')[0])+' (area = %0.2f)' % roc_aucList[i])
```

(pylab is imported as pl) 
Now, the problem is that the above code line produces color curves, while I need them to be in black and white, and since I am drawing several curves on the same plot, each curve should have a unique dashed pattern. In the above line of code, if we remove the color parameter, it still produces colored curves. Could anyone tell me, how I can solve my problem? I would like to add, that its fine if the curves are colored but with different dashed patterns, so that on a black and white printout they would be clearly distinguished.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
figure = pl.figure()
ax = figure.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_color_cycle(['#ffffff', '#000000'])

# your for loop
ax.plot(fprList [i], tprList[i], label= str (fileNames [i].split('.')[0])+' (area = %0.2f)' % roc_aucList[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib (which is what pylab is using) will plot in various colors automatically, but if you want to make them all black, simply replace the `color=colors[colorIndex]` with `color='k'`.

To make them different linestyles, you could make a list like you apparently did for the color, e.g.

```
linelist = ['-', '--', '-.']

# in the loop
ax.plot(fprList [i], tprList[i], color='k', linestyle=linelist[i])
```

Plus your other keywords, of course.  The matplotlib documentation will have a complete set of how you can specify unique linestyles.